# Push Notification Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Does it works with idle model? 
Is there any tutorial of two way communication? system to phone then phone reply back information to system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer these links [A Really Long Post About the Windows Phone 7 Push Notification System](http://www.thisisfanzoo.com/Blog/JeffF/archive/2010/08/02/a-really-long-post-about-the-windows-phone-7-push.aspx)

2)[Understanding Push Notifications](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7-Part-7-Understanding-Push-Notifications.aspx)

3)[Implementing Push Notifications in Windows Phone 7](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Implementing-Push-Notifications-in-Windows-Phone-7.aspx)

Comment: I got to the first link "A Really Long Post About the Windows Phone 7 Push Notification System", where he uses: 'NotificationService.NotificationServiceClient();' 
but I cannot find the NotificationService anywhere in any of the references provided by Microsoft Visual Studio express for WP7. 
Am I missing something here, or is this service basically not provided for the express WP7 version of VS?

Comment: Wait, the NotificationService is the web application right? ( sorry, just beginner =P  ), but still, is it possible to add this web application to a WP7 application in the free Express version of VS, should I add a service reference in my project, or does it work some other way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want two way communication and anything other than a sinple fire and forget process then you are better using websockets in mango to do that.

See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278408(v=VS.92).aspx#BKMK_WebData

Also there is a free webcast on this coming up soon as well

http://www.silverlightshow.net/news/Free-SilverlightShow-Webinar-Networking-with-Sockets-in-Windows-Phone.aspx